# What's meaning of the colors of the arrows on a maven dependency diagram generated from IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_dependency_diagram

The above page doesn't explain the meanings of the arrow colors.
What's the meaning of them?

Thanks.

[image: Maven dependency diagram screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#conflicts_duplicates

> The red arrow points to dependencies that contain duplicates or errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, do you know what the GREY arrows mean?